# Passing MySQL CREATE TABLE SELECT query in Python raise syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, select, create-table

I'm trying to pass a query to sql in a loop in Python:

```
for i in superstar.iloc[:, 0]:

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    loop_cmd = f"""
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS superstar_fwdPlusbwd_{i}; \
    CREATE TABLE superstar_fwdPlusbwd_{i} \
    SELECT a.*, b.CitingPatPublNr as fwd_CitingPatPublNr, c.CitedPatPublNr as bwd_CitedPatPublNr \
    from orbisFirm_focals_basic_feed a \
    left join patents.Patents_ForwardCitations b on a.focal_PatPublNr = b.PatPublNr \
    left join patents.Patents_BackwardCitations c on a.focal_PatPublNr = c.PatPublNr \
    where focal_PatPublNr = "{i}"
    ;
     """
    
    cursor.execute(loop_cmd)
```

but this throws an syntax error:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `superstar_fwdPlusbwd_AU2002310193B2`     SELECT a.*, b.CitingPatPu' at line 1")
```

This seems to be a syntax error inside MySql but this query worked in MySQL Workbench. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Looks like batch (multiquery) is not supported. Execute this as 2 separate queries. And I do not see `{i}` substitution (which seems to be incorrect).

Comment: @Akina thx! Multiquery is the problem! I knew it must be something stupid lol. Please put your comments in Answer so I can accept it!

Comment: It is better if you'll create self-answer - detailed, with reference to and citate from the documentation and code example... think of it as a payment for a consultation.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the parameter of columns in a Mysql table.
You should have used the correct syntax to create a table
Specify the column name, type,etc

Comment: You can directly create table based on select query result. You don't have to pass parameter of columns since select query automatically returns everything.